# How to hide decimal part of the localizedcurrency filter in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, intl

I am using the filter [localizedcurrency](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html#localizedcurrency) to format a price in a multi language 
website. Since this is the price of houses, I don't need the decimal part.

I can't find out how to hide it, besides using the `replace` filter. I wonder if there is a better way, because using `replace` would mean I have to replace a dot in english and a comma in french and so on...

I also can't use some form of substr because the dollar sign can be before or after the value.

I tried passing an int instead of a float to the filter, but it just defaults to `.00`

Thanks!

Comment: try number_format filter with 0 decimal places

Comment: but it won't add the currency symbol on it's locale corresponding position, ex: 100$ / $100

Comment: try round filter then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php):

```
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    echo money_format('%.0i', $number);
```

The `.0` in `'%.0i'` is the right side precision.

You might need to add a filter to your twig extension. Let me know if you need help with that.

Edit:

Looking into intl extension, it seems to call `formatCurrency` method from `NumberFormatter` class, which in turn calls a private  `roundCurrency`, which eventually does:

```
private function roundCurrency($value, $currency)
{
    $fractionDigits = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getFractionDigits($currency);

    // ...

    // Round with the formatter rounding mode
    $value = $this->round($value, $fractionDigits);

    // ...
}
```

But trying to trace where `$fractionDigits` value comes from will go another 2 classes up the hierarchy, and become something as mystic as this:

```
public function getFractionDigits($currency)
{
    try {
        return $this->reader->readEntry($this->path, 'meta', array('Meta', $currency, static::INDEX_FRACTION_DIGITS));
    } catch (MissingResourceException $e) {
        return $this->reader->readEntry($this->path, 'meta', array('Meta', 'DEFAULT', static::INDEX_FRACTION_DIGITS));
    }
}
```

So it *might* be possible to get your current extension to do the rounding, but I would probably go with my own filter as it seems to be easier and i can specify precision on the fly.

Comment: Looks like this could be it, I'll give it a test tonight and I'll get back to you